# String obtained from FileDialog does not display in message box

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to display where a file is saved in a message box with the following code:

```
Sub export()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFileName As String

MyFileName = "MyFileName"

Worksheets("Tab").Copy

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "Path"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        GoTo Nextcode1
    Else
        GoTo Nextcode2
    End If
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"

End With


Nextcode1:
Block of codes that deals with existing file name.
GoTo Nextcode3

Nextcode2:
Block of codes that deals with cancel.
GoTo Nextcode4

NextCode3:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs fileName:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close False
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Worksheets("OtherTab").Activate
MsgBox ("The tab has been exported to " & MyPath & MyFileName & ".")
GoTo NextCode4

NextCode4:
End Sub
```

However, the message box only displays

```
The tab has been exported to MyFileName.
```

With MyPath completely omitted. I tried the following codes

```
PathName = MyPath & MyFileName
MsgBox ("The tab has been exported to " & PathName & ".")
```

And

```
Cstr(MyPath)
MsgBox ("The tab has been exported to " & MyPath & MyFileName & ".")
```

To no avail. My suspicion is that path name obtained from the `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` is not a string object but I'm not sure how to deal with it. Help is appreciated!

Comment: I know this isn't your question, exactly, but you don't need to be going crazy with gotos here.

Comment: Wouldn't your GoTo's always skip over the line that sets the MyPath value?

Comment: Casey, I know, but it's easier for me to organize. Good catch Lars! Should have moved it under `If .Show = -1 Then`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok my bad. The

```
MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
```

line should have gone under

```
If .Show = -1 Then
```